# Why does Highstock initialisation set series variable to null?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I initialise my HighCharts `StockChart` using a configuration object, the `series` param in the object is set to `null` after the initialisation. Why is this?

### Code

```js
//object
var myClass = {
    chartConfig: {
       //some highcharts config

       //some extra params
       url: 'getData.php'
    }
};

myClass.prototype.renderChart = function() {
    console.log(this.chartConfig.series);
    this.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(this.chartConfig);
    console.log("=======================");
    console.log(this.chartConfig.series);
};

myClass.prototype.getSeriesData = function() {
    var self = this;
    $.getJSON(self.chartConfig.url, function(data) {
        self.chartConfig.series = data;
    });
};

var test = new myClass();
test.getSeriesData();
test.renderChart();
```

### Output

```
[Object, Object, Object, animation: false]
=======================
null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line `this.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(this.chartConfig);` with `this.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart($.extend({},this.chartConfig));`

Comment: Any idea *why* HighCharts does this to my series variable when we don't use your solution? Is it some form of garbage collection memory-saving exercise?